# C++ Error in array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, file, pointers

I have a piece of code:

```
int CPUs = GetNumCPUs();
FILE *newFile[CPUs];
```

I got an error. It marks 'CPUs' on the second line and says:
"expression must have a constant value".

I have tried to use `const` but it is not working.

Comment: C++ doesn't have variable length arrays. `FILE **newFile = new FILE*[CPUs];`, or better, use a `std::vector`.

Comment: You need a dynamic array since the number of CPUs isn't "constant"-can't be determined at compile time. Rather than futz around with new and malloc, learn std::vector now and get in the habit of using it.

Comment: Whenever you program in C++ and need a dynamic array, you should think of [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 5):

You can't have a varible sized array in C++. Adding `const` to `CPUs` doesn't help, it only makes the variable read-only, but it's still not a compile time constant because it's initialized by a function at  run-time.

The usual solution is to use a vector:

```
std::vector<FILE*> newFile(CPUs);
```

Answer (score 3):

The value of `GetNumCPUs()` may or may not change every time you run the program - so it is not constant. If you want an array that has a variable amount of elements, try `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<FILE*> newFile(GetNumCPUs());
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `const` doesn't mean "constant". In this context, it means the object is *read-only* — i.e you can't modify the object.  You're trying to create a variable length array, which isn't allowed in C++.  Use `std::vector`, use `new` to allocate memory, or write a C99 program where VLAs like the one you're trying to make are allowed.

Comment: Thx guys :)
I used FILE **newFile = new FILE*[CPUs];

Now it is working :)

Comment: using `new` to allocate memory isn't really an option.

Comment: @user2320928: Don't do that

Comment: Nice edit. I had a problem at first with this because you said const didn't mean constant before

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  `const` *doesn't* mean constant.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `const` doesn't fix all of your problems in this scenario. The problem is that arrays must be initialized at compile time, so if you have a function return a variable (`GetNumCPUs()`) and assign it to a constant (`const int CPUs`), the variable isn't known at compile time but runtime, and the compiler can't allocate data space for the array.

Using an `std::vector`, however, allows for variable storage space.

```
std::vector<FILE*> newFile(CPUs);
```

This should work fine. Here's a couple tutorials:

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/33631-c-vector-tutorial/

Answer (score -2):

CPUs is no known at  compile time.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain really why this is a problem.

Comment: Why not?  You can't assign an unknown value to something.

Answer (score -2):

You should dynamically create the array with [new[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new%5B%5D/)

```
int CPUs = GetNumCPUs();
FILE** newFile = new (FILE*)[CPUs];
```

After you're done with it, you're now responsible for deleting it as well:

```
delete[] newFile;
```

Comment: The poster wanted an array, I gave him array.
I don't understand everyone pushing `std::vector<>` without an explanation / justification.